# Remove string from string using regex and return part of removed

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am trying to extract a component name from a string so I can parse the rest with JSON and also return the component name.

Let's say I have a string as follows:

```
namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}
```

I want to remove the "namespace/Slider" part from the string and return the rest so I can `JSON.parse` it and also want to return "Slider" so the part after namespace as a variable.

EDIT: This is how I was doing it before and it worked until I had a `(` in any of the fields eg: `"caption":"(Name GP"`

```js
const str = `namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}`;

const component = str
          .replace(/\{([^()]|())*\}/gi, '')
          .trim()
          .split('/')[1];
          
const obj = str.match(/\{([^()]|())*\}/gi)[0]
console.log(component, obj);
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+regex*+remove+string+before+parse+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added my original code that was working but had issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Take the substring starting from the first `{` character.

```js
let str = 'namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}';
let idx = str.indexOf('{');
console.log(str.slice(str.indexOf('/') + 1, idx));
console.log(JSON.parse(str.slice(idx)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex match and destructuring to get the relevant parts

```js
const str = `namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}`
const [_,namespace,jsonString] = str.match(/^\w+\/(.*?) (.*)/);
console.log(namespace,JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

Explanation

```
^\w+     // any alpha string from start
\/       // forward slash
(^.*?)   // group from slash to whatever comes next in this case the space
         // space
(.*)     // group from after space to end
```

Comment: This is a nice concise solution! Could you elaborate on how the regex match works?

Comment: @AndyJamesN New update with better variable names

Answer (score 0):

This example uses `replace()`, sub-expressions `(sub-expression)` and back-references `$number`:

```js
let str = 'namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}';
let name = str.replace(/(namespace)\/(\w+)\s+(\{.+\})/, "$2") // Slider
let json = str.replace(/(namespace)\/(\w+)\s+(\{.+\})/, "$3") // {...}
```

The same example example uses `match()` and sub-expressions `(sub-expression)`:

```js
let str = 'namespace/Slider {"showCaptions":true,"circular":false,"autoPlay":true,"showItemNavigators":true,"showItemNavigatorsOnHover":true,"showIndicators":false,"indicatorsPosition":"bottom","showThumbnails":true,"numVisible":10,"numVisible1536":8,"numVisible1280":6,"numVisible1024":4,"numVisible768":3,"numVisible640":2,"changeItemOnIndicatorHover":false,"images":[{"id":1701,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horse.jpeg","alt":"horse alt","caption":"Name some name"},{"id":1699,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/GPJNews_Mongolia_KK_RidingChild_076_web-920x613-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Name GP"},{"id":1238,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/test-scaled.jpeg","alt":"","caption":""},{"id":458,"url":"http://localhost:10019/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/news-scaled-1.jpeg","alt":"","caption":"Paswan a mother who..."}]}';
let matches = str.match(/(namespace)\/(\w+)\s+(\{.+\})/)
let name = matches[2] // Slider
let json = matches[3] // {...}
```

Comment: Thanks this is interesting and gives me something new (sub-expressions) to learn. I am curious why you would choose to use sub expressions in this case?

Comment: It's just a personal preference. I split the string into parts using subexpressions, select the part I want using a back-reference and remove the rest.

Comment: why not match, makes it much simpler and can be done in one go

Comment: Great @mplungjan. I just added an example using match. Thanks!